# Check if the user has explicitly set an excerpt

Tags: functions, excerpt

Is there a way for me to check if the user has explicitly set an excerpt? I need to call the excerpt only if they've specified something in the excerpt field, and not an automatically shortened version of the content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ( has_excerpt( $some_post_id ) ) {
    // Do something here?
} else {
    // Or here?
}
```

**References:**

- [`has_excerpt`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_excerpt)

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Probably should've checked the conditional tags documentation before posting, haha. I'll accept as soon as it'll let me.

Answer (score 2):

This is an alternative to the answer by @tf

The manual excerpt set by a user is stored as a [`WP_Post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) object, `$post_excerpt`.

```
post_excerpt    string  User-defined post excerpt
```

You can access this excerpt inside the loop with `$post->post_excerpt`

You can simply do a check to see if this object is empty or not